# What is Veracode Scan used for?

Tags: veracode

I have made some searches with but, but was unable to discover the purpose of Veracode Scan. Also, I would like to know why veracode scanner is plugged in to Jenkins.

Could anyone help me with this? I am posting this here, as I am unable to find an answer to this even in the wiki pages.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of veracode Scan is that this Veracode software scans your code to detect possible vulnerabilities. It marks the flaws and groups them. Software developers are suggested a possible solution through documentations, or they can mitigate the flaw. The purpose of having Veracode scans as part of Jenkins pipeline, would help the team with the build, you can set in the pipeline if you want to continue with building or not if Veracode flaws are found, for example. You can have a look here [Veracode vulnerability scanning tools](https://www.veracode.com/security/vulnerability-scanning-tools)